vis.js: Create an interactive 3d network graph
I have developed an interactive tool using 2d network graph. However, now I see that an interactive 3d network graph would be more useful to interpret data from various nodes and edges. Unfortunately I have not been able to make a minimal working sample to port the code an no such example is available in the gallery or any other place that I could get with Googling. That makes me wonder if vis.js supports the same. I would be grateful for any inputs on this matter. In the worst case, any free alternative for such 3d network graph plotting tool would need to be used and any suggestions on that would be very helpful too.
